# pass form name variable into url in django

Tags: python, django

I would like to pass the `name` variable of a selected inputbox in my django template into a url without going through the django views or url.py. Is there an easy way to do this.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Chapter</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5 selectContainer">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="chapter_text" value="1"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the `name` value of the `input class` to be passed into the `name` argument of the url in the div button below

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
      <div class="btn btn-default"><a href="{% url 'api:by_book' 'name' %}">Download</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it through javascript.
Store your url value as a JS variable:

```
<script> my_url = "{% url 'api:by_book' 'name' %}"; </script>
```

Change the anchor to a button with a onClick event that calls a function.
In that function you can build the URL with my_url and recovering the name of the input you want with JS. 
After that, make a redirection:

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```

Comment: thanks for the advice @user2872782. I've just used JQuery to sort out everything